# Why is the mid-deck on the Space Shuttle named as it is?

Tags: space-shuttle

The (retired) NASA Space Shuttles has two decks. The flight deck, and the mid-deck.

Why is the mid-deck called "mid-deck"? It is not the middle of three decks. Shouldn't it, strictly speaking, be called the "lower deck" (following naval traditions of decks below the main deck)?

What is the naming convention used for the decks on the Space Shuttles?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Actually, it *is* the middle of three decks, the lower one just didn't get much press.  It was called the Lower Equipment Bay (LEB) or ECLSS bay. It was a pressurized compartment containing mostly life support equipment.

Here's a picture of me in Endeavour's LEB taken from the middeck.

[image]

Here's a schematic from the [1988 Press Handbook](https://archive.org/download/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/Press_Information_Space_Shuttle_Transportation_System_March_1982.pdf).

[image]

Finally, here is a layout of some of the life support equipment in the LEB. I've highlighted the humidity separators, they are the two white devices to the left of my left knee.  This is from the [ECLSS Training Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383445main_eclss_21002.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer. I guess this is as straight from the horse's mouth as you can get :) Maybe you could clear up some other things as well? What constitutes a deck? What makes a "bay" classify as a deck? If I dig a small hole in my lower floor, do I suddenly have a "lower lower floor" even if I can't really use it for anything more than storage? I hope I'm not coming off splitting hairs, but I'm genuinely curious about the definitions and to get clarifications :)

Comment: @GTHvidsten welcome to space stack exchange! All of those names had been set up long before I showed up. A "bay" definitely wasn't always a "deck", there were aft avionics bays back near the main engines that were open to vacuum  and were never referred to as decks. If I had to guess, I'd say it was because all 3 levels in the cabin were enclosed in the pressurized volume and were accessible in flight (although going in the LEB in flight was not all that common, it did happen). So they counted as 3. I'd also guess the bottom floor was a "bay" not a "deck" because you couldn't stand up in it.

Comment: Nice photo! Why cleansuit, hood, mask, but no gloves and also ring on?

Comment: And why mask not over the nose?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket the 'bunny suit' was intended to keep the shuttle clean. I don't know why gloves were not required. The cleanliness guardians taped over my wedding ring with Kapton tape.

Comment: @Michael The 'bunny suit' was intended to keep the shuttle clean. I only had to wear the mask because I had facial hair. My clean-shaven co-workers did not have to wear a mask.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, my *guess* to the Kapon tape on your wedding ring wasn't for cleanliness, but rather to prevent any possibility of direct electrical contact with anything with live electric you might be reaching into, or touching.  Don't want to create any sort of high-amperage shorts that might either damage equipment, or cause the ring to heat up so much that your finger gets burned.  Even with lower voltages, in the right (or wrong, depending on perspective) situation, high amperage could turn a ring almost instantaneously into molten metal.

Comment: @Milwrdfan actually it was just to keep it from falling off my finger. That would have kicked off a possibly long and expensive search to find the foreign object in the shuttle.

Comment: The game is up! You look nothing like an Organic Marble

Comment: @johnDanger my spirit animal https://i.imgur.com/ignpQeH.png

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Bizarre that they didn't require gloves.  I'm also surprised they didn't ask you to simply remove the wedding ring.  I mean, yes, you look adorable with that bunny suit on, but I think the NASA ladies (or gents) could keep their hands off you for a few hours so you could get your job done. ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket At least if you're me, and they are going to let you into a real shuttle, you unquestioningly do what they say to do.

Comment: How many places on the internet are there that you can ask a question about a spacecraft and get an answer from someone who also has a picture of them _in_ said spacecraft!? I suspect just one, and it's right here.

Comment: @stripybadger at work we call this a "humblebrag" and it's totally appropriate here.   And answering with a proto-selfie is by-itself awesome.